# handling multiple user defined jdbc template using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc

I have spring boot project which it can create new jdbc data source for each user with different kinds of configurations based on user's need. It must create connection and list all databases and tables of that data source. I read some [articles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) about the [`jpa`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and [`jdbcTemplate`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) but I didn't find out standard way to handle this problem.

One of my solutions is creating one data source factory and using that to create new data sources but I think it's a general approach and it's not based on spring boot standards.

Is there any standard approach for this kind of problems?